# C# | How Do I Select a Word or Tag in a TextBox by Mouse Location?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, tags, selection

In Windows Forms, if you double click on a word in a textbox, say with text "Do you want to play a game?", the textbox has the uncanny behaviour of selecting a word and the space after it.

It gets worse if you want to select a tag in text like
    `"<stuff><morestuff>My Stuff</morestuff></stuff>"`
If you double-click in 
    `"<stuff>"`
it selects
    `"<stuff><morestuff>My "`
Lovely!

I want it to just select the word, or the tag in those examples. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to listen to the double click event and once fired you select the text you want by coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that DoubleClick's EventArgs does not have a mouse position.
But MouseDown does provide "MouseEventArgs e", which provides e.Location. So here is what I came up with using control key and mouse down to select a tag like `<stuff>`.

```
    private void txtPattern_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control && e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int i = GetMouseToCursorIndex(txtPattern, e.Location);
            Point p = AreWeInATag(txtPattern.Text, i);
            txtPattern.SelectionStart = p.X;
            txtPattern.SelectionLength = p.Y - p.X;
        }
    }

    private int GetMouseToCursorIndex(TextBox ptxtThis, Point pptLocal)
    {
        int i = ptxtThis.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pptLocal);
        int iLength = ptxtThis.Text.Length;
        if (i == iLength - 1)
        {
            //see if user is past
            int iXLastChar = ptxtThis.GetPositionFromCharIndex(i).X;
            int iAvgX = iXLastChar / ptxtThis.Text.Length;
            if (pptLocal.X > iXLastChar + iAvgX)
            {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    private Point AreWeInATag(string psSource, int piIndex)
    {
        //Are we in a tag?
        int i = piIndex;
        int iStart = i;
        int iEnd = i;
        //Check the position of the tags
        string sBefore = psSource.Substring(0, i);
        int iStartTag = sBefore.LastIndexOf("<");
        int iEndTag = sBefore.LastIndexOf(">");
        //Is there an open start tag before
        if (iStartTag > iEndTag)
        {
            iStart = iStartTag;
            //now check if there is an end tag after the insertion point
            iStartTag = psSource.Substring(i, psSource.Length - i).IndexOf("<");
            iEndTag = psSource.Substring(i, psSource.Length - i).IndexOf(">");
            if (iEndTag != -1 && (iEndTag < iStartTag || iStartTag == -1))
            {
                iEnd = iEndTag + i + 1;
            }
        }
        return new Point(iStart, iEnd);
    }
```

Comment: `I see that DoubleClick's EventArgs does not have a mouse position` but you can always get the mouse position in screen coordinates via `Control.MousePosition` and then call `PointToClient` on the text box to get the position relative to the text box's bounds.